# How can you use an external javascript debugger with ie8 in windows 7?

Tags: javascript, windows-7, internet-explorer-8

After switching to window 7, I can no longer use the external debugger with ie8.  I am doing something wrongm what is the trick?

I go to View->External Script Debugger->Open.

Before switching to Windows 7, and list of debuggers would popup.  Now, no list pops up.

Any ideas, anyone?

Grae

Comment: I have the same problem, but only in IE9 32 bit version. In IE 64bit dialog opens well. I have VS2010 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed visual studio .net 2003, and then restarted the browser, and I think computer.  Now it works.  i think maybe it just has poor messaging if you have no debuggers installed.

Thanks,
Grae

Answer (score 1):

Press F-12 while on the page you want to debug.